# How can I identify file names and directories from logs of Unix commands?

Tags: command-line, filenames, command, arguments

I have a data-set of Unix commands as input into terminal and I want to use them to compare user behaviours.

Different users interact with different directories and files (they are all on separate computers). I want to look at which users use the same commands, with the same arguments/parameters (but I am happy to have different filenames/directories as arguments).

Logically to achieve this I should remove the file names and directories from the data-set, then look for similarities, but this is my problem.

How do I identify filenames and directories as command line arguments/parameters?

e.g.
Given
`ls -F thesis`

How can I identify `thesis` as a file/directory (I understand the semantics of `ls` in this case, but I'm looking more broadly, where I will not know semantics of the command issued)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

You need to know the semantics of every command executed.

Any argument given to a command on the command line is just passed to the program which is then free to implement however it feels like. The program doesn't even have to be consistent in how it interprets arguments (it is probably not very usable if it does this).

You also need to consider that some users might have adressed non-existing files - whether as a typo (and those might also occur in the program name), an attempt to see if a certain file exists, to mislead you or for some other reason.
I think I've even seen programs that behaved differently based on whether an given argument was the name of an existing file or not, but did something in both cases.

The tab-completion data that ctrl-alt-delor suggests using is basically a way of encoding the semantics of a lot of (frequently used) commands, but they might (I haven't spend much time looking at those) depends on what shell the user had, and might be changed since. So while the might provide a way forward, it's not without problems.

Answer (score 0):

This may involve some manual work. But when you have created a pattern for a command, it should be re-usable. **I wonder if you can use the config data for tab-completion.** It usually (but not always) knows.